# Cannot connect PrestoDB to Apache Superset

Tags: presto, apache-superset

I am trying to connect prestodb which is running on localhost:8080 to apache presto(installation by scratch not the docker one).

I have installed the Pyhive connector as the indicate in the documentation, also I have tried:

1. hive://hive@localhost:8080/mysql
2. presto://localhost:8080/
3. presto://localhost:8080/mysql
4. presto://localhost:8080/mysql/test
5. hive://hive@localhost:8080/mysql/test
   where mysql is the catalog and the test is the name of the db, and nothing works :/

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was missing the python package "requests" that is needed from PyHive.. So a pip3 install requests solved the issue!